# Best way to store exact duration in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the `TIME` field quite frequently to store a second-accurate duration. However, how would I store something like:

4 hours, 3 minutes, 1.1828999 second

I would prefer not to store it as a float or decimal, but in a way that is clear it's a time duration. How should I do this?

Comment: Time data type does support fractional seconds (depending on your mysql version)

Comment: @Shadow thanks, interesting information was not aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it as a `TIME(6)` to get up to six digits of precision for fractional seconds. [Time precision](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) is a feature introduced in MySQL 5.6.

Storage of fractional seconds costs an extra 3 bytes per column. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time for details.

Then you can format it as you select the value:

```
mysql> select current_time(6), 
 date_format(current_time(6), '%H hours, %i minutes, %s.%f seconds') as `formatted time`;
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| current_time(6) | formatted time                          |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 00:24:53.843700 | 00 hours, 24 minutes, 53.843700 seconds |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

See [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for other formatting options.

Comment: Thanks for adding the bytes it takes!